# What is OpenCL's select operator useful for?

Tags: opencl, simd, gpgpu, conditional-operator

I've noticed that OpenCL has a `select()` function/builtin/operator, which seems to be similar to the ternary operator in C and C++, but not quite. What are the differences between `select()` and `?:`, and why is the former even required if we have the latter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the `select` operator is necessary/useful is for working with OpenCL **vector types**, like `int2`, `float4` etc. Unlike in C++, where you could overload various operators to give them custom semantics - in C (and OpenCL C) there's only the default behavior. For the ternary operator, that means that for

```
x ? expression_for_true : expression_for_false
```

a *single* check will be performed, and the single appropriate value will be used - even if all three operands are of an OpenCL vector type.

Instead, with `select()`:

- All elements must have the same dimensions as vector types, e.g. `int4`, `float4` and `float4`.
- a *different* check is performed for every position within the vector type.
- a *different* choice between elements of the true and false expressions is made for every position within the vector type

Also, to confuse us a bit, the order of parameters to `select()` is different than with the ternary operator: `x ? y : z` corresponds to `select(z, y, x)`.

Thus if

```
x = (int4) ( 1, 0 );
y = (float4) ( 1.2, 3.4 );
z = (float4) ( 5.6, 7.8 );
```

then

```
select(z, y, x) == (float4) ( 1.2, 7.8 );
```

See also the Khronos OpenCL documentation, [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_C.html#table-builtin-relational) and [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_C.html#operators-ternary-selection).